# Change footer text color of doc file

Tags: c#, documentation, ms-word

I have world doc, my requirement is to change footer text color of that documnet.
How can i do this using c#.

Comment: What have you got so far? Show us some code, and perhaps we can help.

Comment: When you say a "world doc", do you perhaps mean a Microsoft Word document?

Comment: yes i mean Microsoft Word document

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of interop for doing this. Read about [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.headerfooter%28office.11%29.aspx) interface.